# xml element is being returned as object HTMLCollection

Tags: xml, object, getelementsbytagname, htmlcollection

I have an xml document that returns a list of map markers.

```
<markers>
<marker name="Marker 1 name" theid="100">
<content>Text goes here</content>
</marker>
<marker name="Marker 2 name" theid="101">
<content>Other text goes here</content>
</marker>
...
</markers>
```

I have some javascript to read through the list of markers and it successfully returns their attributes as variables like `name` and `theid`.

```
<script>
...
var xml = parseXml(data);
var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
var theid = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("theid");
var content = markerNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("content");
...
</script>
```

However I cannot get the javascript to return the contents of the element tag `content`.  In place of the text content I get the message `[object HTMLCollection]`.  Would anyone be kind enough to help me fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit I was missing was textContent:

var content = markerNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("content")[0].textContent;